# Find the values of $p$ for which $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\ln(n)}{n^p} $ is convergent

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

In the context of learning about comparison theorem, using integrals to determine convergence and learning about exponential series (That's what $n^p$ is called right?).

Comment: They are often called $p$-series, "exponential series" is not familiar to me.

Answer (score 1):

If $p\leq1$, then the series is greater than a divergent $p$-series. If $p>1$, show that eventually $\ln(n)<n^{(p-1)/2}$. Then the series will be smaller than the sum of $\frac{1}{n^{p'}}$ where $p'$ is still greater than $1$.

Comment: By the way, if I had to investigate this from scratch, I would just use the Integral Test. But since you are first mentioned the Comparison Test, this is my answer.

Answer (score 1):

$\sum f(n)$ converges iff $\sum 2^n f(2^n)$ converges

Comment: This statement is only necessarily true for $f$ monotone. Otherwise, the latter series could converge, while the original $f(n)$ blows up large on $n$ that are not powers of $2$. OP's $f$ is of course eventually monotone.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** You can use the integral test.